# left join 2 tables not working

Tags: left-join

I have 2 tables:

Table1: '**op_ats**'

```
 | ID1    | numero |id_cofre | id_chave | estadoAT
 |  1     |  111   |   1     |   3      |   1
 |  2     |  222   |   3     |   3      |   2
 |  3     |  333   |   1     |   4      |   2
 |  4     |  444   |   1     |   2      |   3
```

Table_2: '**op_ats_cofres_chaves**'

```
 | ID2 | num_chave |
 |  1  |  A        |
 |  2  |  B        |
 |  3  |  C        |
 |  4  |  D        |
 |  5  |  E        |
```

I have this SQL:

```
SELECT chaves.*, ats.numero numAT, ats.estadoAT
FROM op_ats_cofres_chaves chaves
LEFT JOIN op_ats ats ON ats.id_chave_cofre = chaves.id AND ats.id_cofre = 1
```

With this I get the following result:

```
| ID2 | num_chave | numAT | estadoAT |
|  1  |  A        | 444   |   3      |
|  2  |  B        | NULL  |   NULL   |
|  3  |  C        | 111   |   1      |
|  4  |  D        | 333   |   2      |
|  5  |  E        | NULL  |   NULL   |
```

Now the problem is that I want to filter the rows that are in Table1 but only that have the column 'estadoAT' with values 1 and 2. I've tried to add the line

```
WHERE op_ats.estadoAT = 1 OR op_ats.estadoAT = 2
```

But this makes the following result:

```
| ID2 | num_chave | numAT | estadoAT |
|  1  |  A        | 444   |   3      |
|  3  |  C        | 111   |   1      |
|  4  |  D        | 333   |   2      |
```

Resuming...
My intention is to get ALL rows in the Table2 and join the Table1 rows that have the 'id_cofre = 1' and '(estadoAT = 1 OR estadoAT = 2)'.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to move condition to JOIN clause instead of WHERE.

```
SELECT chaves.*, ats.numero numAT, ats.estadoAT
FROM op_ats_cofres_chaves chaves
LEFT JOIN op_ats ats ON ats.id_chave_cofre = chaves.id AND ats.id_cofre = 1
AND op_ats.estadoAT = 1 OR op_ats.estadoAT = 2;
```